# Making a Groovy generic list Observable

Tags: groovy, observer-pattern, objectdb

I'm using ObjectDB but also want to make the collection inside a persisted object observable, so I have declared it this way:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL) List<Widget> widgets = [] as ObservableList
```

Later on, I create a listener closure and attach it:

```
    def widgetChangeListener = {
        log.debug "WIDGET CHANGE: $it"
    }

    widgets.addPropertyChangeListener(widgetChangeListener)
```

However, when I try to persist the collection, I get this error:

```
Attempt to store an instance of a non persistable type com.greymatter.strategy.Harness$_closure1 - field com.greymatter.strategy.Harness.widgetChangeListener (error 303)
```

Is there any way to make this collection persistable while keeping the closure volatile, so I can observe changes to it?  ObjectDB has a @Transient annotation, but I'm not sure how to apply it to the closure.  If I put it on the def of widgetChangeListener, I get a MissingMethodException.

Are ObjectDB and ObservableList mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy collections are not fully supported by ObjectDB (and by JPA in general). See the list of supported collections in JPA / ObjectDB on [this ObjectDB Manual page](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/types#Multi_Value_Types_).

If ObservableList works well, except the listeners, you may use [JPA lifecycle events](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event) to clear listeners before persisting or updating the entity object (and then set them back if necessary).

Alternatively you can keep 2 list fields in your entity class. An ordinary List that will be persisted, and an ObservableList wrapper of that list that will be set as transient.